# What were the 7 previous births of Brahmarishi Vasishtha?

Tags: scripture, rishi, vashishta, yoga-vashishtha

The **[Yog Vasishtha](https://archive.org/stream/YogaVasishtaOfValmikiValmiki/Yoga%20Vasishta%20of%20Valmiki%20-%20Valmiki#page/n45/mode/2up)** narrates the fascinating story of an immortal crow named Bhushunda who is met by Brahmarishi Vasisth. In **Chapter 22** while reminiscing about his past lives, the divine crow tells Vasishth that he has seen his previous 7 births:

> 8 O sagely son of Brahma, **I remember your eight births in the eight different epochs of the world.** This is your eighth birth in which you have come as a guest to my nest.
>
> 9 At one time you were born of air, and at another of heavenly fire. One time you were produced from water, and at others from emptiness
> and of solid rock.

Now most of us are aware of two births of Vasishth  - ONE as the Manas Putra of Brahma and SECOND as the son of Mitra-Varun when he was born together with Agastya. **I want to know if these other six births of Vasishtha & their details are mentioned in any other scripture?**